# How to step through a mix of Powershell and c# code?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have some c# code mixed in with my Powershell script and it's maddening to try and troubleshoot without being able to put break points where the c# code is and psjobs are.

I'm using Powergui as my IDE. If there is a better way to do this, I'm all ears. I've wasted an enormous amount of time not being able to troubleshoot the c# portion as you would in a normal IDE. The c# works fine when ran in a c# IDE.

Thanks

```
$containerScript = {
    $logfile = "c:\temp\powershell_cSharp.txt";
    try
    {
        "try: " + ([DateTime]::Now.ToString()) | Out-File $logfile -Append;
        $windowFinder = New-Object cSharpNS.CSforPS; # namespace.class
    }
    catch
    {
        "catch: " + ([DateTime]::Now.ToString()) | Out-File $logfile -Append;
        $assemblies = ("System", "System.Data", "System.DirectoryServices", "System.Collections", "System.IO", "System.Windows.Forms", "System.Threading", "System.Runtime.InteropServices", "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement", "System.Security.Principal", "System.Drawing");
        #Add-Type -TypeDefinition $windowCheck -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies -Language CSharp;
        #Add-Type -TypeDefinition $mailAddr -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies -Language CSharp;
        Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cSharpCode -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies -Language CSharp; # add the string of c# code
        $windowFinder = New-Object cSharpNS.CSforPS; # namespace.class
    }

    $error.Clear();
    "Calling windowFinder.Code() in containerScript_" + ([DateTime]::Now.ToString()) | Out-File $logfile -Append;
    Write-Host "Calling windowFinder.Code() in containerScript";
    $result = $windowFinder.code(); #namespace.class.function
    "result: " + $result + "_" + ([DateTime]::Now.ToString()) | Out-File $logfile -Append;
    "error: " + $error + "_" + ([DateTime]::Now.ToString()) | Out-File $logfile -Append;
    "Finished windowFinder.Code() in containerScript_" + ([DateTime]::Now.ToString()) | Out-File $logfile -Append;
    Write-Host "Finished windowFinder.Code() in containerScript";

}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $containerScript;

Write-Host "Finished";
```

Comment: what exactly is the error? can you provide some details as to why you are troubleshooting this piece of code thats executed in powershell

Comment: What Jawad said. Have you tried using a different IDE/Editor, Visual Studio Code the MS free ross platform, cross-language editor and the current editor of choice for many, especially when multiple languages are being used.

Comment: PowerGUI has been discontinued for a long time - really, just change to VS Code.

Comment: I just see powershell code, no C# code. Powershell has .NET types however.